# Making x coordinates from string values(text) for a line graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm really trying hard to learn d3 so I hope that you can help me with this question. I figured out how to scale or map data to the svg for the y coordinate because that data has numbers. I'll show you below how I did it. But for the x values there are no numbers just text like 1mo, 2mo, 3mo ..etc.. I want to turn these into x coordinates for the line graph. They should be spread out evenly along the width of the graph. hopefully you will show me how to get the x coordinates so I could use the line generator to create the path.

```
    var data = [
        {"quarter" : "1mo", "votes" : 400},
        {"quarter" : "2mo", "votes": 200},
        {"quarter": "3mo", "votes" : 1000},
        {"quarter" : "4mo", "votes" : 600}
    ]

    var width = 600;
    var height = 300;
    //supposed to get the domain ([0, 1000])
    var yscale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.votes})])
    yscale.range([height, 0])

    console.log(yscale(30)) //291
    //now I need to get the x cordinates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [d3.scale.ordinal](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal):

> Ordinal scales have a discrete domain, such as a set of names or
>   categories.

```js
var data = [
  {"quarter" : "1mo", "votes" : 400},
  {"quarter" : "2mo", "votes": 200},
  {"quarter": "3mo", "votes" : 1000},
  {"quarter" : "4mo", "votes" : 600}
],
  width = 600;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain( data.map(function(d){ return d.quarter }) ) //<-- a tick for every quarter
  .rangeBands([0, width], .1); //<-- across the range of our graph with 10% padding on outer ticks

console.log(x("1mo"));
console.log(x("4mo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured this out.

Comment: do I really need the `.1` for the `rangeBands`. would it make my line graph look better?

Comment: @jackblank, It's up to you.  The ticks are equally spaced, the `0.1` gives you a little more padding on the first and last tick (spaces it away from the y-axis).  Read [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangePoints).